# I want to allocate an object on the stack with C#

Tags: c#, memory-management

Say I have this C# class:

```
public class HttpContextEx
{
    public HttpContext context = null;
    public HttpRequest req = null;
    public HttpResponse res = null;
}
```

How do I declare an object of it, inside a function, which will be allocated on the stack and not on the heap?
In other words I want to avoid using the 'new' keyword for this one. This code is **bad**:

```
HttpContextEx ctx = new HttpContextEx(); // << allocates on the heap!
```

I know what stack/heap are perfectly and I've heard of the wonderful C# GC, yet I insist to allocate this tiny object, which is here only for convenience, on the stack.

This attitude comes from C++ (my main tool) so I can't ignore this, I mean it really ruins the fun for me here (:

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do this in C#. Not sure if it's possible in .net though through IL.

Comment: @eldarerathis - In this case I'm forced to use C#.

Comment: Well you'll have to think in C# too

Comment: @Poni: Then you should probably just write C# instead of trying to write C++ in C#. I'm not really understanding where the problem is, I guess, but C#/.NET is designed this way for a reason.

Comment: What is the point of creating `HttpContextEx` anyway? The existing `HttpContext` class already offers a `Request` and `Response` property.

Comment: @John Rasch I'm lazy when it comes to passing the same six pointers between 12+ functions, when I could simply pass one nice object.

Comment: @Poni, you only have to pass the HttpContext, since it has the request and response as properties...

Comment: @Thomas Levesque less typing is desired (: I mean instead of "HttpContext.???" I'll write "ctx.res"... like that.

Comment: Every single C# developer here is saying the same thing.  Why ask if you're going to choose to ignore the answers?

Comment: @yodaj007 your question is "illogical" - rethink about it.... Hint: *Telling the future*.....

Comment: To simplify - I had no way to know that these kind of answers would come up, and if I'd know that these are the answers I wouldn't ask, would I ?!? Plus, aqwert's answer is the answer, without all the "bla bla".

Comment: @Poni:  The stack and heap are implementation details in the managed world.  The language only supports the notion of types with value semantics and types with reference semantics.  If you're interested in using value semantics for `HttpContextEx`, make it a struct.  Otherwise, make it a class.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you changed it to a value type using `struct` and create a new instance within the body of a method, it will create it on the stack. However the members, as they are reference types will still be on the Heap. The language whether it be a value or a reference type will still require the new operator but you can use `var` to eliminate the double use of the type name

```
var ctx = new HttpContextEx();
```

Otherwise, take C# as it is since the GC does a great job.

Comment: "but you can use var to elimiate the double use of the type name" << had a good laugh with this one (: Anyway, crystal-clear answer, I thank you for the support!

Comment: Just so I can link this [great article by Eric Lippert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-one) - putting value types on the stack is an implementation detail of all current runtimes, but it could be they are also stored on the heap. ([part 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-two))

Comment: Great answer. Also consider `record struct`s or Value Tuples (with [field names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples#tuple-field-names)).

Answer (score 10):

You can't (and shouldn't) do that. Even if you would use a `struct` (which will be put on the stack), you'd have to use the `new` operator for the contained classes. On a serious note, if you switch to another language, also switch your attitudes.

Comment: Using a ValueType derivative to get stack allocation is just an artifact of the current implementation of the CLR. There is no requirement to have it be so in the spec.

Comment: See Eric Lippert's "The Stack Is An Implementation Detail, Part One", http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx

Comment: @codekaizen: When writing high-performance code, what matters is the current implementation of the platform (and changes likely in the near future), not some theoretical other implementation that the spec might allow. That said, I tend to agree that this class should not be a struct.

Comment: If you are after performance which can differ between using heap and stack you should look into using another language than a managed GC language.

Comment: @codekaizen could you explain just a bit more on what you've said?

Comment: @Poni: While structs can be useful, they should be immutable, and small (eg. 16 bytes or less), as every time they are passed to a subroutine, the whole chunk of memory representing the object is copied, unless you want to use `ref` in all your function arguments.  In 5+ years or C# development, I've yet to find a case where I needed to worry about .Net stack/heap speed.  In short, I just declare classes and let .Net worry about it, while I focus on the app.

Comment: He said that "the stack" is just an implementation detail. It could be gone in the next version of the .net framework, or the behaviour of ValueTypes could change. Read the blog entries Tuzo linked to, it is by one of the implementors of the low level stuff.

Comment: I disagree, I think .NET is a valid platform for writing somewhat fast code, and when optimizing it sometimes makes a difference whether you use 'struct' or 'class', but its performance characteristics are different from C++ and it sounds like the OP is describing a micro-optimization that will probably not improve performance in .NET.

Comment: That's exactly what I was saying, although in a bit different way.

Comment: @Qwertie I agree with what you've said. All of it. Seriously. Yet you know, it's a matter of good practice, more than actually seeking for an **optimization**..

Comment: I often choose 'struct' for 4-16-byte structures, but I do so mainly to save memory in large collections, not as much to avoid heap allocations. An important point is that heap allocation (plus garbage collection) is often faster in C# than allocation (plus deallocation) in C++. The .NET CLR, unlike typical C++ implementations, is specifically optimized for creating large quantities of small, temporary heap objects. I encourage the OP to do some profiling of his own to verify this.

Comment: @Femaref you know what, I'll tell you this - I'll happily accept (minor) performance hit in my C# code if I'll be able to retain my C++ habits.

Comment: If that floats your boat, okay - I just hope (for you) it floats your employer's boat as well.

Comment: HAHAHAHAHAHAHAAAAAAAAAA !! My cat, sitting over here, just jumped coz of my laugh! You killed me.. (: You definitely got my +1 !!!

Comment: Whoa, Poni. You're willing to take a performance hit to avoid best practices in C#? You know, allocating on the stack is not even YOUR habit, it's the compiler or runtime's habit. YOU just declare a variable, the compiler/runtime decides where to put it. So what you're saying is.... you want the .NET runtime to take on the habits of your C++ compiler?

Comment: @Qwertie it's like saying that people don't kill people - it's guns who kill people. What I'm saying is that my PC is **my** PC and I'll make it behave as I say, and when I say allocate on the stack it will do so - besides, something that wasn't mentioned here before - if allocating from the heap it means that the NET framework locks at least one lock (mutex, critical section, etc') while if the desigers were smart (which I believe they were) they made stack allocation lock-less, like in any normal "native code" app.

Comment: To clarify my last comment; Heap means it's shared (by several threads), stack means it's owned by the current thread, so no locking needed.

Comment: @Qwertie I also want to say that when I want to allocate on the stack, like stated, I actually expect C# to allow me to decide where it's best for that specific object to be allocated at. Compiler decides? Not always. Take the C++ 'volatile' keyword for example - it makes extreme change over a single variable. And that's the coder's decision, while he could leave it to the compiler to decide about it, and pray for good...

Comment: C# won't let you choose on a per-object basis whether to put an object on the stack or heap. The closest you could come is to declare a struct X {...} and then declare class Y { public X X; }.... then you would use X for stack, Y for heap. But I have never really needed to do that.

Comment: @Poni:  Sadly, your last three comments here indicate that C++ has caused irreversible damage to your psyche and ability to think abstractly about software.  The definitions you gave of a stack vs a heap made my brain explode.  You presume _far_ too much about the underlying implementation.

Comment: @Greg D so far all I hear from most of C#'ers here is that I should "*let the framework*" do the job - **excuse** me if as someone who comes from C++ I cannot tolerate such things. Even more, I doubt the programming abilities/skills of most gurus here, according to the "intelligent" discussion in this **legitimate** question, which simply looks like there's a whole "breed" of programmers who rely on Microsoft to do the job (no offence MS). Lastly, this question has gone too far over its head and I thank again to aqwert for the simple desired answer. Happy coding all! =)

Comment: If you can accept that different languages or frameworks do things differently - **excuse** me if an open-minded programmer thinks that other platforms can do things differently in comparision to the ones you are used to - then just don't program in them.

Answer (score 3):

You must come from C++. Things don't work like that in .Net.

All reference types are allocated on the managed heap, where they are tracked by the GC. For object references scoped by a function which exits quickly, allocated objects most likely remain only in Generation 0 of the Managed Heap, and this results in very efficient memory collections. The Managed Heap is tuned to handle short lived objects like this. It doesn't even have the same allocation strategy as the C++ heap you may be used to.

This is how the CLR works. If you want to work in another way, try an unmanaged runtime.

Comment: "All reference types are allocated on the managed heap" - No, this is not true.

Comment: This was true when it was written. Not sure what you are contributing here with low effort commentary.

Comment: It's never been true in .NET. Most are allocated on the heap, but there also the Large Object Heap (which is separate from the Heap).  The compiler is free to do other optimizations that might allocate objects elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

In .NET classes are reference types, and structures are value types.

If you really want the type allocated on the stack, you can make a structure. There are however several reasons not to:

- Structures are more complicated to implement correctly. You should stick to classes until you have a good reason to create a structure.
- Structures are intended for types that represent a single unit, while your type is just a container for three separate units.
- A structure should not be larger than 16 bytes to work efficiently. On a 32 bit system you get under that limit, but on a 64 bit system the structure is larger than that.
- A structure should be immutable to work well as a value type, which your type is not.

Finally, there isn't anything inherently bad about allocating small objects on the heap. The memory manager is actually specifially designed to handle small short-lived objects efficiently.

Here is an example of code that doesn't work if it's a structure, but works fine if it's a class:

```
public void SetContext(HttpContextEx ex) {
  ex.context = HttpContext.Current;
  ex.req = ex.context.Request;
  ex.res = es.context.Response;
}

HttpContextEx ctx = new HttpCoontextEx();
SetContext(ctx);
```

Comment: Regarding the code; I understand that. I also understands that by putting the 'ref' keyword I'm all set. Correct, right?

Comment: @Poni: You can use the ref keyword to make that code work, but there are other similar situations where a structure that isn't implemented correctly fails to work.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that C# doesn't support what you are seeking to do.

The object that you are referring to is a class (reference type) and it also contains members that are class types. Memory for class instances is in the managed heap and use of the stack for class instances isn't supported.
*"...reference types are allocated on the heap and garbage-collected..."*
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/choosing-between-class-and-struct

However, you could change your class to a ref struct such that at least the references to its members will be on the stack (although the member instances will be on the heap):

```
public ref struct HttpContextEx
{
    public HttpContext context = null;
    public HttpRequest req = null;
    public HttpResponse res = null;
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/ref-struct

---

As an aside, additional C# stack capabilities:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/stackalloc

Comment: What are you talking about? Please give us some sort of reference to where `using` is in anyway possibility associated with the stack?

Comment: Also, please show how `Span<T>` and `stackalloc` can be used to solve the OP's problem.

Comment: You made an assertions that "it allows memory management analogous to use of the stack". And the big one - "However, it appears to provide the compiler an opportunity to optimize such that perhaps in future versions of C#/.NET, it may even use the stack, or performance may be similar to stack. I.e. using is essentially a try-finally, but I see no reason that using cannot have additional variations/implementations in the future." How so? Where are the references?

Comment: "C# doesn't allow use of the stack for managed objects" - yes it does. Structs go on the stack, generally.

Comment: Your answer is convoluted, meandering, opinionated, unfocused, and misses the point of the OP's question almost entirely. If I could downvote multiple times I would. This is terrible answer.

Comment: The `using` statement doesn't implement "deterministic memory reclamation". The memory is reclaimed in exactly the same way as any other object, **unless it uses any unmanaged memory**. The `using` statement implements "deterministic resource reclamation' where the resource could be file, network, or graphics handlers.

Comment: @Enigmativity Thank you! IDisposable - unmanaged resources only, key distinction indeed. My misunderstanding. I removed the "using" information. Plus, I now know how IDisposable works. In the documentation pattern shown, in the Finalizer (C# destructor), is Dispose(false) called with false, because the managed resources will call Dispose( ) from their own Finalizer (C# destructor), thus freeing their own unmanaged resources? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=net-7.0

Comment: The finalizer does not call `.Dispose()` unless the author of the code has explicitly written it to do so. You cannot ever assume that the `.Dispose()` will be called when an object is collected. You must check the source/documentation or always explicitly call `.Dispose()` on every disposable you use.

Comment: Separation of concept of Dispose() and Finalize/destruct. Understood. Thank you!