# Where the List<int> and int[] are allocated?

Tags: c#

I wanted to run out of the stack memory (1 Mb) by creating this:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>(262144+1);
```

However I didn't receive any exceptions, though the Visual Studio memory profiler says I'm using 9 Mb of memory. So where was this memory allocated?

Comment: @derloopkat Stack is used for static memory allocation and Heap for dynamic memory allocation, both stored in the computer's RAM .

Comment: I think your `List` was not allocated to stack, but to heap memory. take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102547/i-want-to-allocate-an-object-on-the-stack-with-c-sharp

Comment: Arrays are reference types, their storage is always allocated on the GC heap.  Using stack-allocated memory is only possible by using the unsafe `stackalloc` keyword.